# How to have MySQL Slave Replicate From a Master's Master

Tags: mysql, replication

We are using the Following:

- MySQL 5.1.63-community-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
- OS : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4

We have three servers and all servers are enabled with binary logging option

- Server A : Running master on it.
- Server B : it is slave of Server A but also enable binary logs
- Server C : it is slave of Server B.

Our goal to change master server of server c from server B to server A.

- Is that possible in run time without any data corruption?
- What are prerequisites for this?
- How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

## Step 01

On ServerB, run the following commands

```
STOP SLAVE;
SET GLOBAL innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 0;
FLUSH TABLES;
```

## Step 02

On ServerC, run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`

Repeat running `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` until `Seconds_Behind_Master` is 0

Then, run `SET GLOBAL innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 0;`

## Step 03

On ServerB, run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`

For the sake of example, let say `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` looks like this:

```
mysql> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                Master_Host: 10.64.68.253
                Master_User: replusername
                Master_Port: 3306
              Connect_Retry: 60
            Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.003202
        Read_Master_Log_Pos: 577991837
             Relay_Log_File: relay-bin.010449
              Relay_Log_Pos: 306229695
      Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.003202
           Slave_IO_Running: Yes
          Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
            Replicate_Do_DB:
        Replicate_Ignore_DB:
         Replicate_Do_Table:
     Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
    Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                 Last_Errno: 0
                 Last_Error:
               Skip_Counter: 0
        Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 577991837
            Relay_Log_Space: 306229695
            Until_Condition: None
             Until_Log_File:
              Until_Log_Pos: 0
         Master_SSL_Allowed: No
         Master_SSL_CA_File:
         Master_SSL_CA_Path:
            Master_SSL_Cert:
          Master_SSL_Cipher:
             Master_SSL_Key:
      Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
```

Please note the following:

- `Master_Host` (`10.64.68.253`)
- `Master_User` (`replusername`)
- `Relay_Master_Log_File` (`mysql-bin.003202`)
- `Exec_Master_Log_Pos` (`577991837`)

## Step 04

On ServerC, run the following:

```
STOP SLAVE;
SET GLOBAL innodb_max_dirty_pages = 0;
FLUSH TABLES;
CHANGE MASTER TO
MASTER_HOST='10.64.68.253',
MASTER_PORT=3306,
MASTER_USER='replusername',
MASTER_PASSWORD='replpassword',
MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.003202',
MASTER_LOG_POS=577991837;
START SLAVE;
```

## Step 05

On ServerC, run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`

If `Seconds_Behind_Master` is a Number, **CONGRATULATIONS** !!!

## Step 06

On ServerB, run `SET GLOBAL innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 90`;

On ServerC, run `SET GLOBAL innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 90`;

Give it a Try !!!

## CAVEAT

If the majority of your data is MyISAM, ignore all commands that change `innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct`.

Comment: I agree with everything here (+1), except perhaps the recommendation to set innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct so high. IMO it should be lower to ease innodb's checkpoint. Especially if the OP doesn't run the innodb plugin and has no other alternative to tuning checkpoints.

Comment: @DerekDowney since it's MySQL 5.1, I was using the default value of 90. MySQL 5.5 uses 75 but InnoDB caches so well that it becomes an afterthought. +1 on our checkpoint comment.